# AVAudioPlayer started from a C++ callback calls audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying somehow late

Tags: ios, callback, avaudioplayer

could you please give me any tips on where the problem might be? I'm very new to ObjC, so I sort of got stuck.

I use a C++ built library which generates various sounds and I would like to play these sounds using AVAudioPlayer. However, I observe some kind of suprising behaviour of audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying. I'll illustrate it on the following example.

This is my .h file (with the irrelevant stuff left out):

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface mytest_appViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    ....
}

void HaveSoundCallback(const short *psSamples, long lSamplesNum, void *pOwner);
....
@property (nonatomic, retain)   AVAudioPlayer   *player;

@end
```

And this is one part of the implementation:

```
....
#import "MyCplusplusSoundGeneratingLibrary.h"
....
- (IBAction)GoButtonTouched:(UIButton *)sender{
    // calling the C++ made GenerateSound and passing it the callback
    int ret=GenerateSound(couple_of_parameters, HaveSoundCallback, self);
}
```

Generally I don't know how many sounds the GenerateSound function will produce (per one calling), but whenever it produces one, it calls HaveSoundCallback that is supposed to take care of it (it also sends "self" as the "owner" of the sound).

Now this is the callback implementation (it's in the same .mm but outside @implementation...@end):

```
void HaveSoundCallback(const short *psSamples, long lSamplesNum, void *pOwner){
    NSString *OutWave;

    NSLog(@"Entered the callback function");
    OutWave=[pOwner getDocumentFile:@"out.wav"];
    [pOwner SaveSoundData:OutWave pcm:psSamples len:lSamplesNum];
    [pOwner PlaySound:OutWave];
    [OutWave release];
}
```

It means that the callback function saves the sound data to a wav (by calling SaveSoundData) and then it calls PlaySound to play them. PlaySound and audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying implementation are again in the mytest_appViewController class:

```
- (void)PlaySound:(NSString *)WaveFile{
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:WaveFile];

    NSLog(@"Playing started");
    self.player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];   
    self.player.delegate = self;
    [self.player play];
    while (self.player.playing) {
        sleep(0.01);
    }
    [fileURL release];
    NSLog(@"Playing finished");
}


- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)p successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
}
```

I intentionally wait here in the while loop so as to prevent the player from playing all possible returning sounds concurrently - another callback happens after the player stops playing the current sound. But I would like to trigger the finished playing by the player.delegate. So for my experimental (and ObjC "self-tutoring") purposes I implemented the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate.

And now the testing situation: lets say that GenerateSound produces 3 sounds (with short delays between them). I would expect the output console to be something like:

```
Entered the callback function
Playing started
hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
Playing finished
Entered the callback function
Playing started
hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
Playing finished
Entered the callback function
Playing started
hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
Playing finished
```

But instead of this, the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is called at the very end 3 times, i.e.:

```
Entered the callback function
Playing started
Playing finished
Entered the callback function
Playing started
Playing finished
Entered the callback function
Playing started
Playing finished
hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
hi from audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
```

What do I do wrong? Why isn't the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying executed immediately when the playing really finished, and instead it gets stacked somewhere and is executed 3 times at the end?

Has it something to do with the fact that the program is actually all the time inside the C++ library function GenerateSound, and thus the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is executed as soon as GenerateSound is left? And if yes, is there any better way implement the functionality which I'd like to get?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!